# No appropriate default constructor for std::basic_ostream

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I got this error in Visual Studio when  I try to run my code:

```
1>c:\users\pprasha1\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\simulated-anneal\simulated-anneal\erstream.hpp(120) : error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

On this lines:

```
                my_os(user_os),prog(NULL),errstatus(0) { } //HERE
```

Here is the rest of the code for context (search for "HERE" to find the line)

```
#ifndef ERSTREAM_HPP_
#define ERSTREAM_HPP_ 1.6
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#ifndef __GNUC__
#ifndef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
#define INHERIT_ERRORBUF
#endif
#endif

#ifndef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
    class ErrorStream;
#endif

// the streambuf for the error handler, not used directly
class Errorbuf : public streambuf
{
    private:
#ifndef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
      ErrorStream *ehp;           // NOT owned by the Errorbuf !!!
#endif
      char *space;
    protected:
      virtual int doallocate();
    public:
#ifdef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
      Errorbuf() : space(NULL) {}
#else
      Errorbuf() : ehp(NULL), space(NULL) {}
      Errorbuf(ErrorStream* ehpl) : ehp(ehpl), space(NULL) {}
#endif
     ~Errorbuf();

#ifndef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
      void associate(ErrorStream* ehpl) { ehp = ehpl; }    
      virtual int overflow(int c = EOF);    
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
      virtual int underflow() { return EOF; }
#endif    
      virtual int sync();      
};    

class ErrorStream;

struct ErrManipRec        // struct for single parameter manipulator
{ 
        int arg;
        void (*fp)(ErrorStream& ehr, const int a);

        ErrManipRec( void (*f)(ErrorStream& f, const int a ), const int a)
                     : fp(f), arg(a) {}
};

// The actual error handler class
#ifdef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
class ErrorStream : public Errorbuf, public ostream, virtual public ios
#else
class ErrorStream : public ostream, virtual public ios
#endif
{

#ifndef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
    friend Errorbuf;
#endif    

    private:
       static long int efirst;
       static long int elast;
       static long int msgnum;       // count of warning messages

       int errstatus;
       int errcount;
       ostream& my_os;
       char *prog;

       void nomore();

       friend void Warning(ErrorStream& ehr, const int eval);
       friend void    Fail(ErrorStream& ehr, const int eval);
       friend void   Fatal(ErrorStream& ehr, const int eval);

       protected:
           virtual int write_buf(const char* s, const int len, const int eof);   
#ifndef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
       Errorbuf buffr;
#endif                      
      ErrorStream(const ErrorStream& er);
    public:
          ErrorStream(ostream& user_os = cerr) :  errcount(0),
#ifdef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
                    ios( (streambuf*)this ),
#else                                        
                    ios(&buffr),buffr((ErrorStream*)this),
#endif
                my_os(user_os),prog(NULL),errstatus(0) { } //HERE
         ErrorStream(const char *s,ostream& user_os = cerr);
      ~ErrorStream();

#ifdef INHERIT_ERRORBUF
          virtual int overflow(int c = EOF);
#else
          virtual int sync() { return buffr.sync(); }
#endif

      void close();

      void reset()            { errstatus = 0;    }
      int status() const        { return errstatus; }
      int count()  const            { return errcount;  }

      static void first_message(const long int fmsg)        { efirst = fmsg-1; }
      static void maximum_messages(const long int mxmsg)    { elast = mxmsg+1; }

      // set the error status
      ErrorStream& operator=(const int err);

          // add to the error status
          ErrorStream& operator|=(const int err);

      // increment the error status (pre-increment)
          ErrorStream& operator++()           
                       { errstatus++;        return *this; }
#ifndef __ATT2__
      // increment the error status (post-increment)
#ifndef __GNUC__
          ErrorStream operator++(int);           // DOES NOT WORK WITH GCC
#endif
#endif
          ErrorStream& operator+=(const int inc)
                       { errstatus += inc;   return *this; }
          // one way to write error messages
      void warning(const char *msg = NULL);
      void nonfatal(const char *msg = NULL) { warning(msg); }
      void fatal(const char * = NULL );
      void fail(const char *msg = NULL);
      void memory(const void * = NULL );

      void  warning(const int eval, const char *msg = NULL);
      void nonfatal(const int eval, const char *msg = NULL)
                      { warning(eval, msg); }
      void    fatal(const int eval, const char *msg = NULL);
      void     fail(const int eval, const char *msg = NULL);
      void   memory(const int eval, const void * = NULL );    

      // maninpulator version of fatal and warning
          friend ErrorStream& fatal(ErrorStream& er)
                      { er.fatal();   return er; }
          friend ErrorStream& warning(ErrorStream& er)
                      { er.warning(); return er; } 
          friend ErrorStream& fail(ErrorStream& er)
                      { er.fail(); return er; } 

          friend ErrManipRec   fatal(const int eval)
                  { return ErrManipRec(::Fatal,eval);  }
          friend ErrManipRec warning(const int eval)
                  { return ErrManipRec(::Warning,eval); } 
          friend ErrManipRec fail(const int eval)
                  { return ErrManipRec(::Fail,eval); } 

      typedef ErrorStream& (*ErrManip)(ErrorStream&);


    // applicator for the zero parameter manipulators
       friend ErrorStream& operator<<(ErrorStream& err, ErrManip f)
                        { (*f)( err ); return err; }

    // applicator for the one parameter manipulators
       friend ErrorStream& operator<<(ErrorStream& err, ErrManipRec r)
                        { r.fp(err, r.arg ); return err; }    
};

// a nonmember functions, mostly so I remember how to do a manipulator
ostream& terminate(ostream& os); 
#endif
```

Comment: The only warnings I get on GCC after commenting out the `ErrorManipRec` functions were about your member initializer order not matching your member declaration order.

Comment: @chris: on second look, I'd messed up the question.  I see what happened, and fixed it (I think)

Comment: I added  <string> but that doesnt work...

Answer (score 4):

```
class ErrorStream : public ostream, virtual public ios
{
```

Says that your `ErrorStream` is a type of `ostream`, which means that part of itself is an `ostream`.

```
   ostream& my_os;
```

This says that your `ErrorStream` *also* contains a reference to an ostream object.  I'm fairly certain that one of these two is wrong.  Is `ErrorStream` a stream, or does it *contain* a reference to a stream?  Since you seem to default to `cerr`, I believe you want the member.

```
ErrorStream(ostream& user_os = cerr) :  errcount(0),
                ios(&buffr),buffr((ErrorStream*)this),
            my_os(user_os),prog(NULL),errstatus(0) { } //HERE
```

This constructor causes the error, because you initialize the member `my_os`, but you never told it how to construct the parent `ostream` object.  The compiler helpfully tries to default-construct it, but `ostream` cannot be default constructed.  So the compiler doesn't know how to construct the parent `ostream` and errors.

The fix will be complicated, but the first step is to remove the `ostream` parent.  If you want to retain some of that functionality, you can add a conversion operator

```
operator std::ostream&() {return my_os;}
```

Which may let you pretend that `ErrorStream` is an `ostream` in certain contexts.

Comment: +1 The parent cannot be default constructed, and the code doesn't say to construct it any other way.

Comment: i did not get it very clearly... can you like show it to me how to do it..?/

Comment: @PrashantMohan: You've told the compiler that `ErrorStream` _is_ an `ostream`, and also that it has a `ostream` member.  I think what you want is to remove the inheritance.  `class ErrorStream {`.  That will probably reveal lots of other errors you have, so you'll have to address all the problems this would reveal.

Comment: tried that but the error seems to be there..any other solutions..??

Comment: "That will probably reveal lots of other errors you have, so you'll have to address all the problems this would reveal."  You don't have one typo.  You have an entire _concept_ wrong.  You have to fix _all of your code_.